# How to run bashrc in screen detached mode linux for scheduling purpose

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, anaconda

I wrote a bash script called testingb.sh which runs

1. bashrc file to activate created myenv environment
2. python script.
   My bash script (testingb.sh) saved under /home/susan/Newfolder/ looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
python /home/susan/Newfolder/test.py
```

My bashrc looks like below:

```
export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port
export https_proxy=http://server-ip:port
export no_proxy="localhost,svc,node1"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/miniconda/bin
alias envactivate="source activate /anaconda_env/personal/myenv"
alias spython="/anaconda_env/personal/myenv/bin/python"

## >>> conda initialize >>>
## !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/anaconda_env/miniconda/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda_env/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda_env/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/anaconda_env/miniconda/bin:$PATH"

    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
conda activate /anaconda_env/personal/myenv
```

In crontab, I wrote the command:

```
45 22 * * * cd /home/susan/Newfolder && screen -dmS "acaaa" && screen -S acaaa -p 0 -X stuff ./testingb.sh^M > /dev/null
```

However inside the screen , it cannot run the bashrc file due to permission denied error. Please refer to below :

```
./testingb.sh
$ /bin/sh: 1: ./testingb.sh: Permission denied
```

I would like to know how can I run the above bash script (testingb.sh) in detach screen mode in crontab?
Thank you.

Comment: Why is there a `^M` after `testingb.sh`?

Comment: @Cyrus for `screen .. stuff ..` would translate `^M` to ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

can you test below example and check can help you .
You can use the "screen" command to launch a bash process in a detached state. For example:

```
screen -d -m bash -c "bashrc; while true; do echo 'Hello, world!'; sleep 1; done"
```

This will launch a new screen session, run the bashrc command in it, and then execute an infinite loop that prints "Hello, world!" every second.